# Should I have a sitemap or not?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

The articles posted on our website can be viewed through the feeds such as this one for Content Creation category: https://digitalsplendid.net/category/content-creation/.

So, my query is that, should I have a separate sitemap that includes articles under different categories, in addition to links of all the pages and posts?

I believe this makes the process manual but still can be considered if the consensus is having a sitemap helps improve user experience as well as is good for the SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Is the sitemap good for SEO? It is, though its importance has diminished some, given how good the engine crawlers have gotten. I wrote about this for a related question; you can see it here, if you're interested: [Can I delete sitemap.xml from my website, Will it have a negative impact?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122474/can-i-delete-sitemap-xml-from-my-website-will-it-have-a-negative-impact/122483#122483)

Is the sitemap good for user experience? Not really. It's more a signal for engine crawlers than anything for your human users.

In your case, I would recommend including both categories and individual articles in the XML sitemap, but don't include anything twice. Use canonical links to all of the content listed in the sitemap. There is no need to organize it, with content under its respective categories; if your site has a clear structure, the crawlers will themselves discover all of your content by following links, and understand the website hierarchy.